# How to find out what the date was 5 days ago?

Tags: php

Well, the following returns what date was 5 days ago:

```
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d") - 5, date("Y")));
```

But, how do I find what was 5 days ago from **any date**, not just today?

For example: What was 5 days prior to 2008-12-02?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I think a readable way of doing that is:

```
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days', strtotime('2008-12-02')));
```

Comment: I think the date should be a parameter, like 
$dateNow = (new \DateTime())->format('d-m-Y');
$daysAgo = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-5 days', strtotime($dateNow)));

Comment: $n5_daysAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days', time())); @Limon I think it's better

Comment: Since strtotime has default second parameter `time()`, `$n5_daysAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days'));` would be enough for cleaner code

Answer (score 22):

5 days ago from a particular date:

```
$datetime = '2008-12-02';
$periodNDays= 5;

$date = new DateTime($datetime);
$date->sub(new DateInterval("P{$periodNDays}D"));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 20):

find out what the date was 5 days ago from today in php

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-5 day")));
```

find out what the date was n days ago from today in php

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-n day")));
```

Comment: It's weird and totally unneccesary to perform a strtotime() on a date()

Comment: I think the 'strtotime() on date()' is to set the time to 12am, rather than now()

Answer (score 11):

```
define('SECONDS_PER_DAY', 86400);
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', time() - 5 * SECONDS_PER_DAY);
```

Other than that, you can use `strtotime` for any date:

```
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('January 18, 2034') - 5 * SECONDS_PER_DAY);
```

Or, as you used, mktime:

```
$days_ago = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 2, 2008) - 5 * SECONDS_PER_DAY);
```

Well, you get it. The key is to remove enough seconds from the timestamp.

Comment: Cool, but I have the date 2008-12-02 inside a variable $the_date. How to go about it, in this case?

Answer (score 7):

Simply do this:

```
$fifteendaysago = date_create('15 days ago');
echo date_format($fifteendaysago, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-5 day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method in which you know the algorithm, or the functions mentioned in the previous answer aren't available: convert the date to Julian Day number (which is a way of counting days from January 1st, 4713 B.C), then subtract five, then convert back to calendar date (year, month, day).  Sources of the algorithms for the two conversions is section 9 of http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in date_sub and date_add functions to math with dates. (See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

Similar to Sazzad's answer, but in procedural style PHP,

```
$date = date_create('2008-12-02');
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); //outputs 2008-11-27
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to find the same is

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-5 days', strtotime('input_date')));
```