# Work out the date 7 days ago in this format: yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out what the date was 5 days ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708894/how-to-find-out-what-the-date-was-5-days-ago)

I'm trying to work out the date 7 days ago from today in this format: yyyy-mm-dd.

7 is an arbitrary number.

Thanks

Comment: [Many, many comparable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+subtract+days) questions to choose from already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708894/how-to-find-out-what-the-date-was-5-days-ago

Comment: And how are you trying to accomplish this?  In what way is it not working?

Comment: -1 for near 0 research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the timestamp for x days ago and than create a date with php date() function.

```
$x = 7; //number of days in the past

$past_stamp = time() - $x*24*60*60;

$past_date = date('Y-m-d', $past_stamp);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo strftime('%Y:%m:%S',(strtotime('7 days ago')));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
  $days_ago = 7;
  $time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d',(strtotime($days_ago.' days ago')));
  echo $time;
?>
```

Gives:

2012-10-28